# eshot breaking out of table width only in outlook 2007

Tags: outlook, outlook-2007, newsletter

I've got an eshot working in Outlook 2003, Gmail, Hotmail, Yahoo Mail and Thunderbird and its 90% there in Outlook 2007 but there are a couple of bits of text that are breaking out of the main table width.

[image: example image]

See the text "Closing date:" and the date below it... That should right aligned to the edge of the table (which should be the edge of the dotted hr at the top of the image).

For some reason Outlook 2007 is stretching the table and breaking the layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was caused by 3 images lower down in the newsletter. The total width of the 3 images combined was the exact width of the table. Each image was in its own td. Somehow in Outlook 2007 this caused the table to stretch.

I solved the problem by putting the row of tds with the images in into their own nested table with the same width as the outer table.